# Setting up Docker on EC2 instance has permission issues, how do I either reinstall Docker or fix this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ec2-ami

**Issue**

When following the AWS guide for installing Docker (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html), I'm stuck on step 8 `docker info`. Permission should have been added in step 6 so that `ec2-user` can run this without `sudo`, but it can't.

**Error**

`$ docker info`

`-bash: /usr/bin/docker: Permission denied`

**Troubleshooting**

I have restarted the instance, logged out and in, and stopped and started docker.

`id ec2-user` returns `uid=1000(ec2-user) gid=1000(ec2-user) groups=1000(ec2-user),4(adm),10(wheel),190(systemd-journal),992(docker)`

I've installed `docker-compose` and tried to change permissions in other ways:

- `sudo usermod -a -G sudo ec2-user`
- `sudo setfacl -R -m user:ec2-user:rw /usr/bin/docker`

**Desired Behaviour**

I'd like the permissions to be fixed, whether that means reinstalling Docker or just amending permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid typing sudo whenever you run the docker command, add your username to the docker group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
```

You will need to log out of the Droplet and back in as the same user to enable this change.

If you need to add a user to the docker group that you’re not logged in as, declare that username explicitly using:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker username
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That was step 6 that I mentioned in the guide, I've just run it again to be sure.

Comment: Remember that the ability to run any `docker` command implies the ability to root the host.  On a production-oriented (cloud-hosted) system it's not unreasonable to require `sudo` permissions to run `docker`.

Comment: The AWS docs are explicit that it can be done simply. I would be less concerned but my CI runs Docker commands, and I have no reason to believe that it shouldn't be possible.